# How Can I Contribue to a Package in the Vendor Directory

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I fork a project, and it depends on another package in the `vendor` directory. I need to change some package source code and then create a pull request for the package.

What should I do?
Should I fork this package? Then create a independent project? Change the laravel `composer.json` to include this package?

I have searched carefully by google or stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit package on vendor laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727503/how-to-edit-package-on-vendor-laravel-4)

Comment: Thank @GustavoStraube for you answering. I have read it carefully.

Comment: Why the accepted answer for that doesn't fit your question?

Comment: Thank @GustavoStraube for you answering. I have read it carefully.   I have to find a way. [https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel5-package](https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel5-package), I clone the forked project in packages directory, then to maintain it.